# How to find total number of different items within an arraylist.

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, loops

I've done some searching but I wasn't able to find a valid solution. I have an arraylist storing Strings such as gum, socks, OJ, dog food...

I am having trouble iterating the list to determine the total number of differnt types of items.

ie.

```
ArrayList<String> Store = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.Store.add("Gum");
    this.Store.add("Gum");
    this.Store.add("Socks");
    this.Store.add("Candy");
```

The list has 4 total items, but only three different kinds of items (Gum, Sucks, Candy).

How would I design a method to calculate the 3?

Comment: Put them in a map using the value as key.  Get the keys at the end and count them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What [Bhesh Gurung said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085073/276052), but in code:

```
int numUnique = new HashSet<String>(Store).size();
```

If what you actually have is `StoreItems` and need to go through `getName()` then I would do

```
Set<String> itemNames = new HashSet<String>();
for (StoreItem item : Store)
    itemNames.add(item.getName());
int numUnique = itemNames.size();
```

Comment: Would that comprise the entire method or would I put that inside my loop iterating the list?

Comment: @RyanPeters: No iterating necessary, that is it.

Comment: @Ryan Peters: You don't need any explicit iteration, it's done behind the scenes by the code above. `numUnique` will be the number of unique strings, in your case 3.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Suppose that my list actually contained a StoreItem object that has a specific name. Could I set it up like this...         int numUnique = new HashSet<StoreItem.getName()>(Store).size(); ?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `Set` ([`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29)) whose size will give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework... So, if you do not understand the HashSet solution proposed above (or doning the same with a HashMap), think about doing something like this:

Create a new ArrayList

Take an element and check to see if it exists in the new ArrayList

If it is present in the new ArrayList, do nothing. Else add it.

Do this until you have examined the last element of the ArrayList.

Then, the size of the new array list should be the number you are looking for.

Comment: The entire program will be run through a TUI in which the user can add new items and the total should update accordingly. Would this solution still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *lastIndexOf* method and loop through the arraylist.

```
char count=0;

    for(char i=0; i<araylist.size(); i++){
        if(i == araylist.lastIndexOf(araylist.get(i))){
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Tested.